# Configure Leopard Flower (LPFW) to start at boot

Tags: firewall, autostart

I have just downloaded `LPFW` from here: https://github.com/themighty1/lpfw.
Everytime I acces my computer I have to run `sudo ./lpfw` and start the GUI executing `gui/gui.py` to run the program.

Is there a way to make all start automatically at boot?

Thanks